# Getting error while serializing using JavaScriptSerializer in c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

When I am serializing using JavaScriptSerializer in wcf service it gives me below error for defined code.

Code:

```
DataCollection<Entity> detailqueryentityCollection = _serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(detailquery).Entities;
if (detailqueryentityCollection.Count > 0)
{
    listdata = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(detailqueryentityCollection);
}
```

Error:

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON
>   JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set
>   on the maxJsonLength property.

I also add below code in web.config but it doesn't work.

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500000000"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

Please suggest me any solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When instantiating the class yourself, you need to add the value to the `MaxJsonLength` property of the class:

```
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
jss.MaxJsonLength = 500000000;
listData = jss.Serialize(detailqueryentityCollection);
```

Comment: Hi Will Ray, Thanx.Which you suggest and  web.config change both changes are required? or you giving me is enough?

Comment: @chhaya_patel For your use case here you do not need the config file part.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help.